# Subtracting a vector from each row of a dataframe using sweep

Tags: r

While subtracting a static vector from each row of a dataframe, I getting the following error message. 
I'm new to R programming. Can you please help?

Here is the actual dataset.

```
X_train[1:3,]

          V1        V2       V3       V4       V5
1 -0.3877083 0.8440481 1.912346 4.554690 4.040208
2 -1.1077981 0.3935257 2.543470 3.672911 5.718808
3  1.4645829 4.2444438 3.710610 4.250707 3.797844

X_test[1,]

           V1        V2      V3       V4       V5
401 0.7148022 0.1905573 1.39082 3.184805 4.683477
```

The code gives the following error

```
 sweep(X_train[1:3,], 2, X_test[1,])
```

> Error in Ops.data.frame(x, aperm(array(STATS, dims[perm]), order(perm)),  : 
>     list of length 15 not meaningful

I'm not sure how to fix the prob.
The same is working fine when I'm using a toy-dataset like below.

```
 y
  c1 c1.1 c1.2 c1.3 c1.4
1  1    2    4    2    1
2  3    4    5    1    2
3  5    1    8    4    2
 x = c(1,2,3,4,5)

 sweep(y, 2, x)
  c1 c1.1 c1.2 c1.3 c1.4
1  0    0    1   -2   -4
2  2    2    2   -3   -3
3  4   -1    5    0   -3
```

Comment: If `X_test` is a dataframe then also `X_test[1,]` is a dataframe (i.e. a special list). Try `M <- as.matrix(X_test); sweep(M[1:3,], 2, M[1,])`

Comment: Thanks so much, @jogo, 
It worked fine. based on your comment, I also tried to X_test to an unnamed vector. it worked too.
```sweep(X_train[1:3,], 2, unname(unlist(X_test[1,])))```